# How to only exclude two matching fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple fields, I want to select all rows where two fields equal a certain value and where field3 is 1 and field4 is 4, 5, 6 or where field3 is 0. However I need to return results when field3 is 0 and field4 is 4, 5, 6. With this query I am not getting rows back with field3 = 0.

Here's my query,

```
SELECT * from table where field1 = 1 AND field2 = 0 AND (field3 = 1 AND field4 !=4
AND field4 !=5
AND field4 !=6)
```

Comment: you can use the OR clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT * from table where 
          field1 = 1 AND field2 = 0 
            AND (
                  (field3 = 1 AND (field4 = 4 OR field4 = 5 OR field4 = 6))
                     OR 
                  (field3 = 0)
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Cluster and bracket your statement exactly according to your prose text, and you're there.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    field1 = x
    AND field2 = y
    AND (
        (field3 = 1 AND field4 IN (4, 5, 6))      -- field3 = 1 and field4 has one of specified values
        OR                                        -- or alternatively
        (field3 = 0 AND field4 NOT IN (4, 5, 6))  -- field3 = 0 and field4 doesn't have any of the specified values
    )
```

**EDIT:**
Actually - after reading your posting again, you want field4 to be either 4, 5 or 6 and you want field3 to be either 0 or 1 - or am I wrong?
This would mean:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    field1 = x
    AND field2 = y
    AND field3 IN (0, 1)
    AND field4 IN (4, 5, 6))
```